# Reading a 2d array from a file in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file that is 32x32 in size. For example first two lines:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111000
...
```

I want to read and store this file in a 2D array. I have the following java code, but can't exactly figure out how to read the file data. I guess I would need two nested for loops?

```
public static int[][] readFile(){
BufferedReader br = null;
int[][] matrix = new int[32][32];
try {

    String thisLine;
    int count = 0;


    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"));

    while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

    //two nested for loops here? not sure how to actually read the data

    count++;
    }
    return matrix;                      


} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
        } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
return matrix;
}
```

Comment: That's simple : how do you convert a String of  digits into an array of integers ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each line in your file is a row, and, for each row, a character is an entry:

```
// ...
int i,j;
i = 0;
while((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    for(j = 0; j < thisLine.lenght(); j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(thisLine.charAt(j));
    }
    i++;
}
// ...
```

This is just a starting point... there may be many more efficient and clean ways to do this, but now you have the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one more loop, since the while loop you already have is functioning as the outer loop.

```
while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    for(int i = 0; i < thisLine.length(); i++){
        matrix[count][i] = Character.getNumericValue(thisLine.charAt(i));;
    }

count++;
}
```

Comment: Identical to my answer ;)

Comment: Got it thanks... And to write the 2D array back to file I just change it from BufferedReader to BufferedWriter?